# ProductDetail.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the following error -

*ProductDetail.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')*

```
import React from 'react';
import {useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import products from '../products';

const ProductDetail = () => {

    const { id } = useParams();

    const product = products.find((p) => p._id === Number(id));

    return (
        <div>
            {product.name}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductDetail;
```

products.js

```
const products = [
  {
    '_id': '1',
    'name': 'Samsubg A001',
    'description':
      'testinggggg',
    'brand': 'Samsung',
    'category': 'Mobile',
    'price': 10,
    'Stock': 20,
    'rating': 4.5,
    'Reviews': 12,
  },
```

Comment: If no result if found using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) it returns `undefined`. You don't appear to have a product with the matching id. Without more context, we cannot provide a true answer except to say - plan for no match found with conditional rendering or a similar pattern.

Comment: What debugging steps have you tried already? It's incredibly unlikely that a question with nothing but an error message and a code block is of any quality. We expect that before asking a question you do research yourself, and if you're still stuck that you provide the details around your attempts and what you found in your searching.

Comment: @BrianThompson Solved the error by replacing strict equality operator(===) with equality operator (==)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `product` variable is not undefined? Seems like you are trying to access to `name` property inside a undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can short-circuit by checking if the product is undefined or you can use optional chaining like this `product?.name`

Answer (score 0):

### const product = products.find((p) => p._id === String(id));

That will work